# Asp.Net WebApp URL has extra folder information when running in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a web application in C# using VS 2008 and Framework 3.5 . All of the sudden, when I run the app in debug, the URL becomes "http://ServerName.com/IncidentReporting/(S(vrrpiuumx3ueqfbm0ljjnh45))/Default.aspx" rather than what I am expecting which is "http://ServerName.com/IncidentReporting/Default.aspx". This is causing major heartburn with some of my image links that get embedded in an email that the application generates. Any ideas why this is happening? It also happens when I deploy the project to the production web server.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: This comes from cookie-less sessions.  It's a problem with ASP.net's browsercaps config.

Comment: You would need to post code and information about your debuging attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cookieless sessions enabled. This is actually a big security risk. In your web.config, make sure you have:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

Comment: As this is an internal site only (had to change server name and domain to post the question) I wasn't too worried about the security issue. However I will say this is the first time I have ever noticed this behavior. Switching to cookies fixed the problem though and I thank you for the help!!!